# Migrar una base de datos mysql a postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Debo migrar la base de datos de mysql a postgresql y solo tengo el archivo bk.sql de exportar mysql. Cómo logro importar el archivo bk.sql en postgresql?

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso al servidor mysql para generar tus propios archivos de exportación? Eso facilitaría mucho la migración de datos. Echa un vistazo a esta herramienta: https://pgloader.io/

Comment: https://github.com/philipsoutham/py-mysql2pgsql